# How to compile C++ windows exe without import table

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compilation, compiler-optimization

I need to make an exe program that has no import table

iam using C++ i don't use any API even loadlibrary and getprocaddress i get handles to them in runtime

still when i build the application using visual studio 2013 [also tried visual studio 6]

the resulting exe has many imports from kernel32.dll

- Address  Ordinal Name                        Library

  -------  ------- ----                        -------

  0040E000         MultiByteToWideChar         KERNEL32

  0040E004         RtlUnwind                   KERNEL32

  0040E008         HeapAlloc                   KERNEL32

  0040E00C         ExitProcess                 KERNEL32

  0040E010         TerminateProcess            KERNEL32

  0040E014         GetCurrentProcess           KERNEL32

  0040E018         GetCommandLineA             KERNEL32

  0040E01C         GetVersion                  KERNEL32

  0040E020         RaiseException              KERNEL32

  0040E024         HeapFree                    KERNEL32

  0040E028         HeapReAlloc                 KERNEL32

  0040E02C         HeapSize                    KERNEL32

  0040E030         HeapDestroy                 KERNEL32

  0040E034         HeapCreate                  KERNEL32

  0040E038         VirtualFree                 KERNEL32

  0040E03C         VirtualAlloc                KERNEL32

  0040E040         IsBadWritePtr               KERNEL32

  0040E044         SetHandleCount              KERNEL32

  0040E048         GetStdHandle                KERNEL32

  0040E04C         GetFileType                 KERNEL32

  0040E050         GetStartupInfoA             KERNEL32

  0040E054         UnhandledExceptionFilter    KERNEL32

  0040E058         GetModuleFileNameA          KERNEL32

  0040E05C         FreeEnvironmentStringsA     KERNEL32

  0040E060         FreeEnvironmentStringsW     KERNEL32

  0040E064         WideCharToMultiByte         KERNEL32

  0040E068         GetEnvironmentStrings       KERNEL32

  0040E06C         GetEnvironmentStringsW      KERNEL32

  0040E070         WriteFile                   KERNEL32

  0040E074         GetLastError                KERNEL32

  0040E078         SetFilePointer              KERNEL32

  0040E07C         FlushFileBuffers            KERNEL32

  0040E080         CloseHandle                 KERNEL32

  0040E084         SetUnhandledExceptionFilter KERNEL32

  0040E088         IsBadReadPtr                KERNEL32

  0040E08C         IsBadCodePtr                KERNEL32

  0040E090         GetCPInfo                   KERNEL32

  0040E094         GetACP                      KERNEL32

  0040E098         GetOEMCP                    KERNEL32

  0040E09C         GetProcAddress              KERNEL32

  0040E0A0         LoadLibraryA                KERNEL32

  0040E0A4         ReadFile                    KERNEL32

  0040E0A8         SetStdHandle                KERNEL32

  0040E0AC         LCMapStringA                KERNEL32

  0040E0B0         LCMapStringW                KERNEL32

  0040E0B4         GetStringTypeA              KERNEL32

  0040E0B8         GetStringTypeW              KERNEL32

  0040E0BC         ReadConsoleInputA           KERNEL32

  0040E0C0         SetConsoleMode              KERNEL32

  0040E0C4         GetConsoleMode              KERNEL32

  0040E0C8         CreateFileA                 KERNEL32

i used debug and release option both give the same problem
i used multithreaded MD same problem

any ideas

Thanks for your time in advance
[Note: my code include some inline assembly]

==================================================================

to reduce the size of the problem. I configured the entry point on the linker option i pointed to main

this helped to reduce the import table to the following

Address  Ordinal Name              Library

-------  ------- ----              -------

00406000         HeapAlloc         KERNEL32

00406004         ExitProcess       KERNEL32

00406008         TerminateProcess  KERNEL32

0040600C         GetCurrentProcess KERNEL32

00406010         HeapFree          KERNEL32

00406014         VirtualAlloc      KERNEL32

00406018         HeapReAlloc       KERNEL32

===============================================================

reduced even more

1st - uncheck the include default libraries in linker options

2nd - add MSVCRT.LIB to the linker command

now the import table is

Address  Ordinal Name   Library

-------  ------- ----   -------

00405000         malloc MSVCRT

00405004         exit   MSVCRT

00405008         rand   MSVCRT

Comment: In order to start a process in windows requires calls to kernel32.dll. Are you asking how to start a process without that? Even low level filters requires resources from this. Dynamic linking would still use the need of a function table.

Comment: I have seen EXEs with only 2 or 3 imports loadlibrary,getprocaddress only
and even EXEs that get that at runtime as i do

Comment: To use getprocaddress requires dynamic linking to kernel32. This is why you seeing the functions on heap or stack.

Comment: i get handle to getprocaddress and loadlibrary on runtime
iam not using them in my code

Comment: That doesn't matter you still have to load the kernel up front to start the process don't you?

Comment: ok then only loadlib and getprocaddress virtualalloc virtual free then why the other imports!!

Comment: The function table is showing the entirety of the kernel32.dll. You can not load partial portions of it...once you link to it, all of it will be loaded.,

Comment: You might be able to get away with creating a `.def` file and importing only what you want. Not sure though..

Comment: I think .def file is for exporting functions not importing

Comment: Hi CantChooseUsernames. I am sure that you can create a def file to define what you are seeking, however, that does not change that the fact that once you link to a library all functions within that library will be placed on the stack. The op is not talking custom libraries but core api dll's.

Comment: I know that once you loaded a library you loaded it all in memory but iam talking about the import table in the EXE file. i think it doesn't have to include all the APIs from the imported library

Comment: Ok, please educate me when you find the answer please:)

Comment: at least one import: ExitProcess() ?

Comment: lrb i found a solution not elegant but it works

Comment: lrb 1st for malloc and exit i implemented them in my code using virtualalloc and exitprocess which i can get at runtime from kernel32.dll

Comment: lrb 2nd for rand i replaces msvcrt.lib with libc and that solved the problem and now i have an EXE without import table

Answer (score 3):

You see all these entries in IAT for kernel32.dll because visual c++ runtime code calls all these functions directly. For example:

```
#include <Windows.h>    // include prototypes

// note that we need to link with kernel32.dll import library 
// (kernel32.lib) to call its functions directly;
// { Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input ->
// Additional dependencies } will contain "kernel32.lib" in the list

int main(int argc, char* argv[]);

int mainCRTStartup()
{
    GetCommandLine(...);   // direct call, so linker will create entry in IAT for kernel32.dll

    ...
    main(argc, argv);      // your main function that linker will search for
    ...
}
```

Also note that even if you link with kernel32.lib and don't call any of its functions directly (that's the purpose of import library after all) your binary will not even contain `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` for kernel32.dll, so linking with kernel32.lib has absolutely no effect in this case.

Create console application with this code:

```
int my_entry_point()
{
    return 0;
}
```

To create exe file with no imports follow these steps:

1. { Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Ignore All Default Libraries -> Yes (/NODEFAULTLIB) }
2. { Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point -> my_entry_point }
3. { Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Security Check -> Disable Security Check (/GS-) }

This will tell compiler not to emit calls to security check functions, so linker will not have to resolve them.

Compile your program. Examine it in PE Explorer to make sure it has no imports (`DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress` is 0).

Note that your program links with kernel32.lib and other import libraries for system dlls (see Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies). However it has no effect since you don't use CRT and don't call all these functions in your own code.

The interesting thing is that you don't need to import `ExitProcess`. Windows will immediately call `RtlExitUserThread` from ntdll.dll when `my_entry_point` function returns. This call instruction does not use IAT or any other redirection, it is call that will lead us directly to `RtlExitUserThread` function.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually it is not possible to have a Windows executable (well known as Win PE) without an import address table (IAT). But of course, technically it is possible to have an executable with an empty IAT and such an executable will be of no use or will be very difficult to code and maintain.

As we know, a computer program is defined to have at least one output and for that some kind of library dependency will be there. This library dependency is enough to fill the IAT. A C++ program that only uses the function printf() will cause to have a few number of entries in the IAT.

A normal executable will have plenty of entries in the IAT, as you listed. There are guys who do encryption to protect the executable file. They will use a technique known as IAT Mangling. They will considerably reduce the entries that are present in the IAT.

On a practical side, at least, the import table should contain a module entry for "Kernel32.dll" and that entry should contain the sub sections for the "LoadLibrary" and "GetProcAddress" APIs. Knowing how a Windows Loader loads and starts the execution of an executable will help to understand the critical role played by the IAT.

Whenever an executable is going to be loaded by the Loader, among other things it will check the integrity of the IAT. Any mismatch such as missing DLLs, function signature mismatch will cancel the execution of the executable.

There is a series of scholarly article on Win PE by Matt Pietrek. It clearly explains the role played by the IAT. You can read it from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx).

By the way, if you are aiming to reduce the size of an executable, have a look at [this](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S572.aspx) article on Liposuction Tools.

Comment: you are right but i even don't need to use getprocaddress or loadlibrary. i can get them using in-line assembly by parsing PEB structure. which i did

Comment: I could create a console application in VS 2012 that doesn't have any entry in the IAT. I didn't specify MSVCRT.lib to the linker. Why do you specify MSVCRT.LIB to the linker command?